# How to read from model properly in MVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am just wondering what the correct way to read from the model in an MVC type setup is. I understand what its purpose is and how to implement it, but I need some further assistance when it comes to deeply integrating it into a larger application.

For example: I have an app that has a UITableViewController class that utilizes multiple other classes within, such as subclasses for UITableViewCells or custom headers.

How would I access the same instance of my model file from all of those classes? Do I need to setup a property on the original UITableViewController class and then just pass it between subclasses? Or do I need a singleton kind of setup?

What is the best way to access the same model file across multiple different classes that need to look at the same information?

Comment: The easiest and safest way is **passing pointers of your data model** to the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will pass the model objects between controllers and views. For example, your `UITableViewCell` subclasses should accept a model object (usually as a property) from the table view controller. Then the table view controller is just responsible for organizing the model objects into rows and sections. It delegates their interpretation and rendering to the cells.

In some cases you may have multiple table view controllers that need the same organization of model objects. In that case, you can create a model controller that the table view controllers can query.

I've long used a singleton to manage my model store, and let the table view controllers query it. Recently, however, I've moved a bit more towards passing the model store to the table view controller. There are trade-offs either way, and so far I haven't found either to be clearly the better solution; just different. Singletons are a bit easier to develop; passing instances are a bit easier to test. But in any case, the views shouldn't be going directly to the model store; they should just be handed the model objects (usually just one) they're going to display.

The one thing you should carefully avoid is having view controllers talk to other view controllers who are not their immediate parent or child (and even then, they should minimize this to initial setup and a possible "I'm done; here's the result"). View controllers are not the holders of data. No view controller should ever ask another for model objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to setup a property on the original UITableViewController
>   class

Probably yes. If you are implementing a table view, you probably have an array of your model object though, so you would declare an `NSArray` property in your `UITableViewController` subclass. If other classes have to access the same model objects you need to pass them along. Singletons are not a good choice in this case.

Consider this simple example. Your model object is called `Person` and has some properties that hold information about a person (name, birthday, photo etc.). In your `PersonListViewController` (your subclass of `UITableViewController`) you have an `NSArray` property containing all these `Person` instances. 
When the user selects one of them, you initialize a `PersonDetailsViewController` (an other subclass of `UITableViewController`). This view controller will have a single `Person` property (which is the person it will display information about). So after initializing the new `PersonDetailsViewController` you pass the selected `Person` instance to it, so it can display the correct information.
You might also have a subclass of `UITableViewController`. For instance to display the person's birthday in a fancy way. This `BirthdayTableViewCell` class however does not need (or should) have access to the `Person` instance. It just has to have an `NSDate` property that you can set from `PersonDetailsViewController` when setting up your table view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my case I need to have certain actions performed after a user selects an object from within a UITableViewCell. The problem is that the cells are subclasses so I can't send that action to the original TableViewController from within that subclass. So should I have a model class that essentially has public methods to communicate between the two? Like a property that is set to -1 in the model and if I need an action to be triggered I set that to 1? Then my TableViewController can read that and perform the action?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Explaining your concrete use case might help.

Comment: I have a UITableViewCell that has a UIImageView in it. When a user taps the UIImageView I want a UIActionSheet to show. That action sheet needs to show in the UITableViewController. What I'm asking is if a good way to do this would be via the model. Have a property, which is set to -1 by default. If I tap the UIImage in the cell I set it to 1. Then in my UITableView I can look at the model and see that it's now 1, which means I show an action sheet. After the actionsheet is dismissed I set it back to -1. Bottom line: need to show action sheet after UITableViewCell UIImage is tapped.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer to this question. There are multiple ways how you could do this. I still don't quite understand your way, but here are a couple of ideas, how I would approach this problem. When you set up the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` make sure that a method in your `UITableViewController` subclass is called when the image is tapped. You could do this by using a `UIButton` instead of a `UIImageView` and define the correct target/action pair, put an invisible `UIButton` above your `UIImageView` or subclass `UIImageView` to respond to touches.

Comment: Then you implement that method and show the action sheet.

Comment: Do you mean to use delegation for the UIButton target/action method? So that when it's pressed I will run a method in my UITableViewController class? Doing it that way would mean I would need to have the TableViewController as the delegate for my UITableViewCell, correct?

Comment: Something like that, yes. But with a target/action you don't need a delegate, only if you decide to subclass `UIImageView`. You can just set a target for your button (the view controller) and an action (what ever method you want).

Comment: You don't need a model object here. Delegation from the view to the controller is plenty. Exactly as you say: the table vie controller would be a delegate for the table view cell. The delegate method should be along the lines of "cellDidActivateImage:" or "cellDidTap:" or the like. It's not the view's business that this will lead to an action sheet (so the delegate method should not be "displayActionSheet:"). But it sounds like you have exactly the right idea in mind.

Comment: Following the target/action pattern as DrummerB suggests is fine as well. You may want to model your cell's API on the UIButton API.